# ISNUMERIC AND EMPTY STRING

Tags: vb.net

I want to create an application where if someone enters a number, it is entered into a listbox but if someone enters an alphabet or leave the textbox blank, a message box should appear. How to do this? Thanks.

```
  Private Sub btnRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRecord.Click
            Dim grade As Double
            grade = CDbl(txtGrades.Text)
            If grade >= 0 And IsNumeric(grade) = True Then

                lstGrades.Items.Add(grade)
                txtGrades.Text = " "

            ElseIf txtGrades.Text = " " Then
                MessageBox.Show("Number cannot be less than 0", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)

            ElseIf IsNumeric(txtGrades.Text) = False Then
                MessageBox.Show("Number cannot be an alphabet", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: Use the Double.TryParse method.

Comment: ... or look at a MaskedTextBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your logic and eliminate errors by using `TryParse`.  This method determines if a String can be converted to a Double and returns either True or False along with the converted value:

```
   Private Sub btnRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRecord.Click
      Dim grade As Double

      If Double.TryParse(txtGrades.Text, grade) Then
         lstGrades.Items.Add(grade)
         txtGrades.Text = " "
      Else
         MessageBox.Show("Number cannot be an alphabet", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
      End If
   End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like he also needs to check that grade is greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson Unclear because his description clashes with his code.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I just wanted that if someone enters an alphabet or leaves it blank, then a message is showed as otherwise this will create runtime error. As long as no runtime error occurs, then its okay.Thank you very much.